# In LRU square algorithm, is the least-recently-used row always zero?

Tags: c, algorithm, lru

My copy of Hacker's Delight is at home, and the web resources I've found aren't clear on this detail.

I have written the following 8-level LRU, using the well-known "row-column square" algorithm. (Is there a better name?).

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
  uint8_t rows[8];  
  uint64_t cols;
} lru_state;

void lru_init(lru_state *this) {
  this->cols=0;
}

void lru_up(lru_state *this, int used /* in 0..7 */) {
  this->rows[used]=0xff;
  this->cols &= ~(0x0101010101010101 << used);
}

int lru_get(lru_state *this) {
  int i;
  for (i=1; i<8 ; i++) {
    if (0==(this->rows[i])) return i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I would like confirmation of my assumption that the least-recently-used row will be all zeroes.  It seems to work, but I don't have the math to prove it to my satisfaction.

So, is this right?  Or do I need to compute the minimum Hamming weight for each row?

Comment: Note: your for loop in `lru_get()` never tests `rows[0]`.  Is this your intent or what you are hoping to employ?

Comment: I just let that be the fall through.  Moving it up into the loop (with no fall through) depends on the answer to this question.

Comment: My 2 cents worth of expertise:  Agree with your assertion.  Portability issue: Some machines are big or little endian and that affects functionality.  An good compiler will deal well with `uint64_t FF = 0xff; cols |=  FF << (used*8);` vs. `rows[used]=0xff;` and negated the need for the union.

Comment: @chux, how would you handle the test in lru_get() ?  I think my version is OK; I don't really care about memory arrangement as long as rows[i]=0xff operates on the same byte as 0==rows[i].  Do you agree?

Comment: `if (0==(cols & (FF << (i*8)) )) return i;`  or set up a mask and shift it rather than increment `i`.   BTW: Does your assertion fail/work if `lru_up()` is never called - do you care? IDK.  I do not see the initial condition, but then if I knew more I could assume something.

Comment: I'll edit in the initializer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

We can prove it by contradiction:

Suppose the LRU candidate (the byte with most zero bits) is c and has a bit set in position x.

This means that line x has not been used after line c, therefore x must have all the zero bits that c has, plus a zero in position x.  This is a contradiction as c is the byte with most zero bits so we conclude that c cannot have any bit set.